Firebase Realtime Database get data from between array index number
Solved my problem.. I edited my database..

Then I decoded like that:
 let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: MathLevel].self, from: jsonData)

Question:
I want to retrieve data between two values in Firebase Realtime Database. How can I do this? For example, when I get levels between level 1 and level 4, my code works fine. However, when I enter a value different from level 1 as the starting point, my code gives a Decode error. How can I fix this?
When I try this code.. it is working..
.queryStarting(atValue: 1)
.queryEnding(atValue: 3)

but When I start this code from 2 or 3 different from 1..
.queryStarting(atValue: 2)
.queryEnding(atValue: 5)

I got decoding error.
Failed to fetch levels: valueNotFound(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead", underlyingError: nil))

Snapshot.key:
When I got decode error.. this is from catch block..
fooo: Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600000c715c0>(
<null>,
{
    id = "7b167080-c3cf-4a75-8650-11c76573d8c7";
    isLevelFinish = 0;
    levelCount = 2;
    math =     {
        bottom =         {
            id = "8c295c70-0e5c-4aa2-a4eb-e5030a0a5f3c";
            mathPositionType = bottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "23ab8f52-55d8-4534-b0e2-3e6df6bbbc19";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 19;
                },
                                {
                    id = "86542a75-658a-4329-b5ed-89db338c8af1";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "0d6cb6eb-b2e5-4eec-8eb4-5deaf0e11eaf";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        left =         {
            id = "6a3b9ed3-2c86-4cf6-9056-17b0e925028d";
            mathPositionType = left;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "8b3300b7-8c5b-4441-b197-64c4ed7df51f";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "cd460733-e76f-47e0-9baf-1598b9aeb1d5";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "d5b915b2-9f9d-43d7-8a06-51dbf11c5d8c";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 9;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftBottom =         {
            id = "ba1e4ba3-4a74-46a4-b41b-6469a1fbd2a8";
            mathPositionType = leftBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "5e4f2bb1-68f1-481b-98a2-e11f64e7d8a1";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "e34e04f1-4ed8-4607-bf9e-31c9c1fa5982";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "f321c3bc-2ed7-465a-8399-2a473ffabf95";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 5;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftTop =         {
            id = "f1d68135-987f-4e7b-9d93-c4c2d4d3c6b3";
            mathPositionType = leftTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "f2c3824e-74d5-4b9f-97df-9a588c6fcd34";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 3;
                },
                                {
                    id = "795d9e5d-32b3-4ec7-acee-3788c3d3b711";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "c6801c85-c3d5-4c5a-b816-3cf2f4b39c1e";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        right =         {
            id = "4b35a206-d68f-4d5c-9d26-dc6f734ffbcb";
            mathPositionType = right;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "728be631-7b0f-498d-bbf6-2d9ec2a1d755";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 30;
                },
                                {
                    id = "8322b3f4-343f-4bb6-8269-e151d7cb4f1b";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "0f5b04b8-6f0b-4e83-92de-392cbd2147b0";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightBottom =         {
            id = "36dfc6b0-d24a-4b92-a6e4-745f304d6b6d";
            mathPositionType = rightBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "3ddc36f1-9f26-421e-951d-dbf72e6cf54b";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "88d5ff96-0b38-4ef1-a6c5-4b510ca3d4c8";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "/";
                },
                                {
                    id = "9caa3f5f-57a8-4db4-8c3c-d951f05807af";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 4;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightTop =         {
            id = "d31c328d-11c3-499b-87c3-d9b4b0de1650";
            mathPositionType = rightTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "d0bb9426-3346-4897-8960-3a3d883e5f48";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 7;
                },
                                {
                    id = "c5153aa1-8e67-456e-9521-f23d4f1528d1";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "f75b7b5f-f7ac-4f06-94b6-b8ae6dabe5f0";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        top =         {
            id = "aa5474de-f3de-4d23-92c2-4f7d40b9f5b7";
            mathPositionType = top;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "28dd91ef-1e17-4c2a-842c-f2f4d9d19e07";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "f1223b98-ff26-4b0b-bfb1-9e5d8c3c2fd6";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = x;
                },
                                {
                    id = "65b7bcde-d147-498a-85f7-f24ab67ae0d2";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
    };
    total = 12;
},
{
    id = "d6ff74f8-30da-4481-8741-f6b19c787c4e";
    isLevelFinish = 0;
    levelCount = 3;
    math =     {
        bottom =         {
            id = "5c5a34ef-13e7-409b-a7c7-458ea0323275";
            mathPositionType = bottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "5a580e21-8ae8-4b93-9350-6f8a2fe02e1d";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 18;
                },
                                {
                    id = "f11dc373-422b-481d-9216-c354d5b7a53d";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "2f8d0638-3b77-419d-babb-c0fc881b21d4";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        left =         {
            id = "083d6183-ace0-43d5-843e-70dcf37df332";
            mathPositionType = left;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "a2a4eec3-f78c-4d94-9af2-5ae7fa5e27d1";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "a781c46a-6a35-49ff-8f4b-307b5de0e812";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "3e0ab9e8-7db2-4e1e-b916-9e13da34be91";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 8;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftBottom =         {
            id = "1b91c4dc-d628-4e8b-9472-2920f7882abf";
            mathPositionType = leftBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "9469a31b-7b3d-4760-ae7e-f038da47d81e";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "31b01323-29db-4e1b-b204-011e6109a38a";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "7310ea3d-2ef2-4b0a-a8b3-07c8e4b1e6b7";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 6;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftTop =         {
            id = "3e2f95d2-0aa1-4a25-a9af-b8cc2e299ac4";
            mathPositionType = leftTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "2b85ed11-c2c4-4a7d-afe7-76347a8d9700";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 5;
                },
                                {
                    id = "e2c87591-60fc-47fc-bb7d-3b448d22c205";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "78e9733c-e2b8-41c6-a0a1-d7ef548d86dd";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        right =         {
            id = "4a1253e4-9a2e-45b7-8cf7-3e25645101e5";
            mathPositionType = right;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "b775a95e-f88e-49e5-a223-4b3b12ad2b10";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 20;
                },
                                {
                    id = "ed26b0be-1cde-4645-82cb-9bbd44f4f56d";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "d22026e5-2d1a-4c1f-9a80-63a5c71fcd02";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightBottom =         {
            id = "40bff604-ea45-4b07-a933-5bfc82103fa1";
            mathPositionType = rightBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "0ff4b1a0-7b61-47de-aea6-8b4010dfb579";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "dd0243a6-76fa-41bc-b351-0d562739ee01";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "/";
                },
                                {
                    id = "a320e623-c5c6-4a16-bfc7-05b0eec4fc61";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 2;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightTop =         {
            id = "04a46c1c-27e6-498b-8c0b-fb55d8310e34";
            mathPositionType = rightTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "d9d0674d-06a0-4f3d-8a68-738ac2c9df1a";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 4;
                },
                                {
                    id = "4e13d06d-42bc-4d6c-8fc3-94b6469ec5e0";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "ab34a6b1-3a26-4631-8d5b-c5c95c53ee56";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        top =         {
            id = "5c56351c-d162-4b8e-bd1a-0a7b7f2a4b0f";
            mathPositionType = top;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "d1603c98-306d-4a35-b2b6-d158a4e8d40d";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "918e9c2f-9bcb-4708-8705-4091207477d0";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = x;
                },
                                {
                    id = "fbc9b9e8-130d-4986-bf5a-2a2d6c39ec1a";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
    };
    total = 11;
},
{
    id = "8db68c89-e869-4b60-a7a8-0535f7b830c1";
    isLevelFinish = 0;
    levelCount = 4;
    math =     {
        bottom =         {
            id = "80c2f706-93ae-487d-b91b-4eb6ef5b28da";
            mathPositionType = bottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "a7fbd442-72f7-4639-97ee-861b4211b6c3";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 21;
                },
                                {
                    id = "44d43863-16c2-43de-9f1e-61b19af6b0b3";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "8e4420ec-8c8a-4ba3-8ef3-573f8d8dd97b";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        left =         {
            id = "0ac328db-0b5f-4421-bfb2-cdd5e413a98a";
            mathPositionType = left;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "1daae900-e7c3-4968-8320-78e9c3700e64";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "3c9da902-1d1a-4ae5-8d5c-473acb7e327d";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "5fa69f1f-ea79-406d-84a6-e126c04c3301";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 10;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftBottom =         {
            id = "7e6497fc-fbe5-4185-8353-07bb4ad8b393";
            mathPositionType = leftBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "682787b0-fb8d-4902-905e-8b2a54a2aace";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "7f944f84-459e-4033-b0d4-5f4c77f2fc24";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "2cf94096-86f4-4b4f-9439-c380e67f3a12";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 4;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        leftTop =         {
            id = "0572a706-82a2-4ed3-8d1f-861acfb0eaec";
            mathPositionType = leftTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "2255152a-b420-4995-bebd-5d8a6d2e49af";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 7;
                },
                                {
                    id = "15d18917-5a40-45a2-b6b1-e6769b38fffb";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "2200aadd-9029-4f7d-8e9f-22fc0da74b7f";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        right =         {
            id = "b2d8d184-8fae-47da-9961-dbb73c6b5ef8";
            mathPositionType = right;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "62abf1d0-fba0-4b00-9fd8-2338a51c2181";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 16;
                },
                                {
                    id = "5460f8f7-df80-472a-b420-83abbd210b5a";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "-";
                },
                                {
                    id = "d91ed11e-35d0-490a-93a0-4dd41a87708f";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightBottom =         {
            id = "73f8f10c-73ee-4026-86ba-88159876b99e";
            mathPositionType = rightBottom;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "87548b65-7000-42b0-b316-5c0844a1493d";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "6d9b20b3-95e3-4c87-84a8-70b6a09afdb4";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "/";
                },
                                {
                    id = "dc5c152e-7484-4cc0-b948-1ed12de6b5d6";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 8;
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        rightTop =         {
            id = "2dff0b8a-12e6-47e6-946a-69a2fa45c57e";
            mathPositionType = rightTop;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "1b933345-18b1-40b3-918a-fb79ad993c5e";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = 3;
                },
                                {
                    id = "3fa1b515-03da-4f51-ae4a-4d5278c24978";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = "+";
                },
                                {
                    id = "e107742e-8c7b-40d6-8194-473fb536b7a7";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
        top =         {
            id = "66584f27-b142-4c5a-8349-e0be81b2851b";
            mathPositionType = top;
            mathQuestion =             (
                                {
                    id = "ffded8c5-cd88-4636-b7d7-17cba3a6c840";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                },
                                {
                    id = "7f79c4ec-8f6e-4b47-9c84-13ba63d3d240";
                    isQuestion = 0;
                    value = x;
                },
                                {
                    id = "cabb93de-0f5c-42c4-9d00-d38ec3da04a5";
                    isQuestion = 1;
                    value = "";
                }
            );
            questionStatus = none;
        };
    };
    total = 15;
}
)
)

RealtimeDatabase:

How can I fix this ?
private static let ref = Database.database().reference()

static func observeLevels() -> AnyPublisher<[MathLevel], Error> {
    let subject = PassthroughSubject<[MathLevel], Error>()
    
    ref.child(.mathLevels)
        .queryOrdered(byChild: "levelCount")
        .queryStarting(atValue: 3)
        .queryEnding(atValue: 5)
        .observe(.value) { snapshot in
        do {
            
            guard let value = snapshot.value else {
                throw NSError(domain: "DataError", code: -1, userInfo: nil)
            }
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value)
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([MathLevel].self, from: jsonData)
            subject.send(response)
        } catch {
            print("fooo: \(snapshot.value)")
            subject.send(completion: .failure(error))
        }
    }
    return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


Using sequential, numeric keys in Firebase (i.e. the keys directly under your mathLevel node) is an antipattern. Did you see Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase?

Did you try to use pushed kyes instead?
